# Why am I unable to see information from multiple jobs? After I have pulled data from indeed webpage

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

I am looking to pull data from an indeed webpage pertaining to the job cards. However, even when just searching using the tag a, I can only find information relating to one job card, why is this? I have attached my code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_url(job_role, minimum_salary, location):
    #Generate url from job role, minimum salary and location
    
    #.format(Role, min Salary, Where)
    template = 'https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q={}+{}&l={}'
    url = template.format(job_role, minimum_salary, location)
    return url

url = get_url('Graduate Engineer', '20000','guildford')

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')

cards = soup.find_all('a')
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Opening the URL https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q=Graduate%20Engineer+20000&l=guildford I see only one job. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks Andrej! You are correct, when checking in another window I had used £20000 instead of 20000. The problem lies with the 20000, each search should be 'role ' + '£'+'minimum salary'. I highly appreciate your quick response, it is much appreciated.